# Free alternative to Charles

Tags: macos, proxy, http

Does anybody know a free alternative to [Charles (an HTTP debugging proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)), preferably with a GUI and similar features?

Features that I'm interested in:

- Inspect HTTP requests/responses (header, body, etc)
- JSON syntax highlighting and formatting
- Request filter (by host, URL, etc)
- Search
- Would be awesome if it could render HTML (Charles can't do it)

Comment: Please read http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation

Answer (score 13):

You can also check out [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org) which even has a web interface. You can inspect HTTP request/responses and even filter requests by certain parameters.

It doesn't render HTML like you asked but it sure gives out the raw response which might be enough.

Another suggestion I can think of is the developer tools in Firefox which render HTML and also support request filtering. You can obviously inspect HTTP requests in Firefox too.

Answer (score 11):

Proxyman is exclusively built on native macOS and it's designed with intuitive UI, so you can start proxying HTTPS easily and quickly.

The free version includes all essential feature and all debugging tools, such as Repeat and Edit, [Breakpoint](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/breakpoint), [Map Local](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/map-local), Map Remote, [Scripting](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/script)

You can intercept the HTTP traffic from [iOS](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-device) and [Android](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device) devices too. Proxyman also has Built-in automatic scripts to override HTTP Proxy and certificate for [iOS Simulator](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-simulator) and [Android Emulator](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device/automatic-script-for-android-emulator).

[image: Proxyman Dashboard]

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) (https://proxyman.io | https://github.com/ProxymanApp/Proxyman).

Comment: To prevent this being closed as spam, you must declare your connection to the product. "Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)"

Comment: @Nghia Tran can you have a look on this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061316/network-connections-not-shown-in-proxyman

Comment: Wow, thank you. I installed it and was up and running in less than 5 minutes. All certificate setup (mac and Simulator) is “one click” and “just works”. I won’t be touching Charles with a ten meter pole, ever!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/charles-alternative/). It's a great Charles Proxy alternative that I've been building, and I think it's exactly what you're looking for. It:

- is 100% open source, and all the features you're looking for are free
- has a fully powered editor for request & response bodies, powered by the same internals as VS code
- does targeted interception - it can launch browsers, terminal windows, or Android interception all automatically for you, and then intercepts only that specific traffic. That means no interference with the rest of your machine, no noise from other apps, and no need to globally trust an new certificate authority.
- requires zero setup: open the app, click a button, instant HTTPS interception
- has a far more powerful & flexible rules engine for building rules to rewrite and breakpoint your traffic
- looks beautiful, is much nicer to use, and works fully cross-platform

A picture's worth a 1,000 words:

[image: A screenshot of HTTP Toolkit in action]

Answer (score 1):

You are the two following Charles like :

1. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Fiddler for macOS runs on mono, so don't expect the same smooth appearance like you get on Windows.

2. [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org)

Wireshark is more relevant for capturing everything over the wire (and then filtering by protocols) and not directly useful(easily) for scripting HTTP responses on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

User BurpSuite by PortSwigger

https://portswigger.net/burp

The community edition is well enough to inspect HTTP/HTTPs traffic and more, only it cannot render HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [Proxycat](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/proxycat/id1562957266) which has a macOS version and an iOS version.