# Is it possible to find out what video link an App on iOS accesses?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, links

I have an App on iOS that plays a TV channel at no charge, but a PC version is not available on the company website. I tried to watch the channel on the iPhone, it was not enjoyable. I'm wondering if there's a way to find out what video link the App accesses that way I can watch the TV channel on the computer. Thank you!

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252348/free-alternative-to-charles

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps do it by installing [`mitmproxy`](https://mitmproxy.org) on a Mac (or other computer) and proxying your iOS traffic through it.

You can setup the proxying on the device in the Settings app in the  WiFi tab (when using WiFi) by tapping the circled i, and then at the bottom tap "Configure Proxy". Here you want to set it to Manual and point it to the IP address of your computer and the port number, where you have `mitmproxy` running.

If the app uses TLS/SSL communication (that is an encrypted link), which is often the case, you will have to install and trust a CA certificate for `mitmproxy` that is generated when the program is started the first time. You can read more about that here:

https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/

In some cases, apps use certificate pinning and other measures to disallow proxying, and you then can't really use `mitmproxy`.